# How to add <script> tag into an div id with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to add  tag into react  but componentDidMount always run before render. how do I add script into  and run it together.

```
componentDidMount () {
    function loadScript() {
        var script= document.createElement('script');
        script.type= 'text/javascript';
        script.textContent = 'var Module = { TOTAL_MEMORY: 536870912, errorhandler: null, compatibilitycheck: null, dataUrl: "Release/Arctopia_Path_Monopoly_v1.1.1GL.data", codeUrl: "Release/Arctopia_Path_Monopoly_v1.1.1GL.js",memUrl: "Release/Arctopia_Path_Monopoly_v1.1.1GL.mem",};';
        document.getElementById("play").appendChild(script);

        var script0= document.createElement('script');
        script0.type= 'text/javascript';
        script0.src= 'TemplateData/UnityProgress.js';
        document.getElementById("play").appendChild(script0);

        var script2= document.createElement('script');
        script2.src= 'Release/UnityLoader.js';
        document.getElementById("play").appendChild(script2);
    }
    loadScript();
    this.setState({ update: true })
    console.log("insert script")
},

render () {
    return (
        <div id="wrapperOthers">
            <div className="container text-xs-center" id="play">
                <h4>{ this.data.colCourse.name }</h4>
                <canvas id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" height="600px" width="960px"></canvas>               
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend to create this script as separate js file and import/require it(since you are using JSX I assume you are using ES6, so I will write example in ES6). Then you can keep only `this.setState({ update: true })` and add inside the div under conditional { this.state.update ? importedScript : null }

The whole code might look like this:

```
/*At the very top of your file*/
import importedScript from '../path to the file'

componentDidMount () {
    this.setState({ update: true })
    console.log("insert script")
},

render () {
    return (
        <div id="wrapperOthers">
            <div className="container text-xs-center" id="play">
                { this.state.update ? importedScript: null }
                <h4>{ this.data.colCourse.name }</h4>
                <canvas id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" height="600px" width="960px"></canvas>               
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

You won't need any child appending, script creartion and etc. Your code will be much more tidy and it can help with your issue.